# How to set a alignment at right siede when drawing a PDF in ios6?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

can anyone can know me how to set alignment at right when we draw a PDF.

my code is like below and i want to set a textField(text1.text ,text2.text,text3.text) value as text alignment right

```
- (void) drawHeader
{
    CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(currentContext, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

         NSString *textToDraw =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\t\t \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t Display Device (# rooms: Good   %@   /Better   %@   /Best   %@   ) \n \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t$500-----------------------------------------------------------------$5,000   \n \n \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t$5,000--------------------------------------------------------------$50,000 \n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t$50,000------------------------------------------------------------$200,000  \n  \n   \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\ \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\ \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\ \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\ \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\Display Devices Total:\t\t %@ ",text1.text ,text2.text,text3.text,allDiaplayDeviceAll.text] ;



    UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0f];

    CGSize stringSize = [textToDraw sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset-2*kMarginInset, pageSize.height - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

CGRect renderingRect = CGRectMake(kBorderInset + kMarginInset, kBorderInset + kMarginInset, pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset, stringSize.height);

    [textToDraw drawInRect:renderingRect withFont:font lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried by specifying `UITextAlignmentRight`:

```
[textToDraw drawInRect:renderingRect withFont:font lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap alignment:UITextAlignmentRight];
```

Actually, for iOS6 (if you are not targeting iOS5), the correct constant is `NSTextAlignmentRight` (`UITextAlignmentRight` has been deprecated, but it still works).